# Q: Loading CodeEffects RuleEditor instance with a different source object

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I am attempting to load a selected source object from a dropdown menu into the Rule Editor.

I'm already creating the RuleModel from the selected source object in a new instance of the RuleEditor and loading the settings into CodeEffects from the RuleEditor's client settings (calling my LoadSettings function again).

At this point the source object is changed, but the rule fields have not (After selecting a different class, executing rules for the old source object throws this error: No "field" nodes with "x" value of the "y" attribute found)

How to I go about re-rendering the RuleEditor instance in my view?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an unrelated issue with loading one of my source objects: The `MaxTypeNestingLevel` was set too high and was causing `editor.GetClientSettings()` to return a string too long for an Ajax post...

I should have checked that first.

Simply calling `LoadSettings()` after the event that changes the source object is all that's needed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.